# how to get place details from place id in google places api for python

Tags: python, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API with Python to build a collective intelligence app for food. e.g. what restaurants are around, what ratings they have, what are their timings, etc.

I am doing the following in Python:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

API_KEY = ''

google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    location='Mumbai', keyword='Restaurants',
    radius=1000, types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT])

if query_result.has_attributions:
   print query_result.html_attributions


for place in query_result.places:
    print place.name
    print place.geo_location
    print place.place_id
```

And it returns me something like this:

```
Subway
{u'lat': Decimal('19.1156005'), u'lng': Decimal('72.9090715')}
ChIJV2JWaObH5zsRt-FrEb8lrtM
Aroma's Cafe
{u'lat': Decimal('19.116867'), u'lng': Decimal('72.90982199999999')}
ChIJSWijB-bH5zsRVLE5ipsxvHU
Chili's
{u'lat': Decimal('19.1161942'), u'lng': Decimal('72.90909789999999')}
ChIJ4_2UcubH5zsRWMemt2WTsLc
Mainland China
{u'lat': Decimal('19.1154358'), u'lng': Decimal('72.90858159999999')}
ChIJ88dcaObH5zsRWLT4KyCLkI8
The Yellow Chilli
```

Now I want to have the details of each restaurant (like their ratings, reviews, timings). How can the information be retrieved with `place_id`?

Comment: Try calling `place.get_details()` followed by `place.details`. It's a dictionary object.

Comment: @Kris but `place.details` returns me information about only 1 restaurant. I have 20 in my `query_result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this (scroll down for the documentation):

https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places

It's got all of the calls you need. For example:

```
for place in query_result.places:
    place.get_details()
    print place.rating
```

Will get the ratings for each of your places. Pretty much everything is in that github link for you :)

Comment: I am following this link only.. but when I fire above command `for place in query_result.places:
    print place.rating`  It returns me info for 4-5 restaurants and then raise an error `GooglePlacesAttributeError: The attribute requested is only available after an explicit call to get_details() is made.`

Comment: @user2927983 call `place.get_details()` first. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ Kris  I am trying with this method `GooglePlaces.get_place(place_id ="ChIJSWijB-bH5zsRVLE5ipsxvHU")`  but it returns the error. `TypeError: unbound method get_place() must be called with GooglePlaces instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`  Don't know how to deal with this

Comment: I am new to python.. Don't know how to do it.. sorry for this stupid question. can you help?

Comment: I'm not a smart man. Try this: `google_places.get_place(place_id ="ChIJSWijB-bH5zsRVLE5ipsxvHU")`. Your call was right, but you need to call the method from an instance of the class `GooglePlaces`