# How to make a dataframe from latitude and longitude in google places api for python

Tags: python, google-maps, pandas, dictionary, google-api

I am using the Google Places API with Python by using the code from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282235/how-to-get-place-details-from-place-id-in-google-places-api-for-python) .

I got latitude and longitude for locations of a type like this:

```
{u'lat': Decimal('19.1156005'), u'lng': Decimal('72.9090715')}
{u'lat': Decimal('19.116867'), u'lng': Decimal('72.90982199999999')}
{u'lat': Decimal('19.1161942'), u'lng': Decimal('72.90909789999999')}
```

Now I want to save it as a data frame with latitude and longitude columns.
How can I do that?

This is the code I'm using
  from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

```
def GoogPlaces(lat,lng,radius,types,value,key):
  API_KEY = key
  LOCATION = str(lat) + "," + str(lng)
  RADIUS = radius
  TYPES = "bus_station"

  google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)

  query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    location=LOCATION , keyword="bus_station",
    radius=RADIUS)

  if query_result.has_attributions:
      print query_result.html_attributions

  for place in query_result.places:
      print place.geo_location
for item in pointofinterest:
  a = GoogPlaces(lat, lng, radius, item, value,'Mykey')
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code you used to get those values back?

Comment: @snapcrack I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['lat','lng'])

ctr = 0
for place in query_result.places:
    for key, item in place.geo_location.items():
        df.loc[ctr, key] = item
    ctr += 1
```

This allows you to iterate over the dataframe for each geospatial value returned and keeps your position in the dataframe index with `ctr`.

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: 'Place' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @asikhalaban my apologies, i forgot to add `items` to `place`, since it's a dictionary. try now. (also it should be `key` and `item` when iterating over the dictionary.)

Comment: What's the key? It didn't work. Also, what's items here? AttributeError: 'Place' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Each `place` is returning a dictionary, like `{u'lat': Decimal('19.1156005'), u'lng': Decimal('72.9090715')}`. So the keys are 'lat' and 'lng', and the values are 'Decimal('72.....')` etc. Unless that's some kind of strange tuple? Can you check by running `for place in query_result.places: print (type(place.geo_location))`? It may just be an issue of me having left out `geo_location` in my code. It's been a very long day.

Comment: This is the result I got. <type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'> I think I got a solution for it. Just give me a couple of minutes then If it works I'll share my solution with you :) thanks.

Comment: Yeah then the issue was just that I had forgotten the `geo_location` at the end of `place`, which was a typo

Comment: Yeah, Thanks again for your help. I have one more question cannot get more than 10 places in Google API?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how that API works (I've never used it, which is why the syntax threw me a bit). That's probably fit for a different question on its own

Comment: Thanks again for your help ;)